# Snowflake - Calculating days from multiple tables based on specific condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can anyone help in snowflake query to get the correct result. I am working on snowflake and have 3 tables as ZBK, ZLF and ZT05

TAG(int) is the day of the month. It is only to compare with day(inv_dt) It can be 00
MONA(int) is the No. of Months i.e. 01 means 1 Month...
FAEL is the day of the month i.e 20 means 20th day of the month.

TAG1 is the column which has additional days which needs to be added in the final sum calculation without any condition.

If the inv_dt is less then TAG then the no. of days calculation should consider specific Term for a vendor and apply the rule of calculation as per that specific tag row.

example - for 1st row, Tag is 16 and day(inv_dt) is 7 which is less then Tag then while calculating no. of days it should take value of Fael i.e. 20 and mona as 00 and count no. of days from 7th Feb to 20th Feb which is 13.

For 2nd row, Tag is 25 and day(inv_dt) is 17 which is less then 25 but greater then 16 of the same vendor and term group. then calculation should be Fael i.e. 20 and mona as 01 and count no. of days from 17th March to 20th April which is 34 (14 day of March + 20 Days of April)

```
Table ZBK              Table ZLF        ZT05
Inv_Dt    Vendor  |  Vendor   Term |  TAG  FAEL MONA Term  TAG1
7/02/23   100428  |  100428   AA5  |  16   20    00   AA5   00
17/3/23   100428  |  100429   CA2  |  25   20    01   AA5   07
26/3/23   100428  |                |  31   10    02   AA5   15
22/4/23   100429  |                |  00   07    02   CA2   5

Desired Output (sum_days column) - List column just for reference.
inv_dt     term  tag tag1   fael  mona  sum_days  list
2023-02-07  AA5  16   00     20    00     13      13
2023-03-17  AA5  25   07     20    01     41      14+20   + 07(tag1)
2023-03-26  AA5  31   15     10    02     60      5+30+10 + 15(tag1) 
2023-04-22  CA2  00   05      7    02     51      8+31+7  + 05(tag1)
```

I have a sample query on SQL as below

```
with joined as(
select ZBK.Inv_Dt, ZLF.TERM 
  from ZBK
    join ZLF on ZBK.Vendor = ZLF.Vendor)
select Inv_Dt, TERM, TAG, FAEL, MONA, sum(FAEL) sum_days,
       string_agg(FAEL, '+') within group (order by n) list
from(
  select Inv_Dt, a.TERM, TAG, FAEL, MONA,n, 
       case 
       when MONA = 0 and FAEL > day(Inv_Dt) then FAEL - day(Inv_Dt)
       when n = 0 then datediff(day, Inv_Dt, last_day(Inv_Dt)) 
       when n = MONA then FAEL 
       else day(last_day(dateadd(month, n, Inv_Dt)))
       end days
  from joined a
  cross apply(select top 1 * from ZT05 b
                    where b.TERM = a.TERM and day(Inv_Dt) < TAG order by TAG) b,
  cross apply(select n from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) v(n) where n <= MONA) v) t
group by Inv_Dt, TERM, TAG, FAEL, MONA
```

I am looking for a query on snowflake.
When I am running this query after modification of `string_agg to listagg()` and `cross apply to lateral` in snowflake. I am getting error of `SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`
Thank you

Comment: Hi - is there is a reason why table ZLF has 3 identical records? Trying to join to it will triplicate the rows unless additional steps are introduced to deal with duplicate rows

Comment: @NickW 
Yes, This is to first join ZBK and ZLF on vendor to have Inv_dt and Term in the same table. Then to join new table to ZT05 on Term.

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually answered my question: why has table ZLF got these values repeated 3 times “ 100428   AA5 ”?

Comment: Hello @NickW
Sorry, I have corrected the question, It is 2 records only in ZLF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
SELECT ZBK.INV_DT
,ZLF.TERM
,T1.TAG, T1.FAEL, T1.MONA
,DATEDIFF('DAYS',ZBK.INV_DT, 
    ADD_MONTHS(
                DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(ZBK.INV_DT), MONTH(ZBK.INV_DT), T1.FAEL)
                ,T1.MONA
              )
         ) "SUM_DAYS"
FROM ZBK
INNER JOIN ZLF ON ZBK.VENDOR = ZLF.VENDOR
INNER JOIN ZT05 T1 ON ZLF.TERM = T1.TERM AND T1.TAG = 
    (SELECT MIN(T2.TAG) FROM ZT05 T2 WHERE ZLF.TERM = T2.TERM AND T2.TAG > DAY(ZBK.INV_DT) )
ORDER BY ZBK.INV_DT
;
```

I've assumed that the tag value has to be greater than the invoice day but if the rule is <= then you'll need to adjust the "T2.TAG > DAY(ZBK.INV_DT)"

Comment: Thank you so much Nick. It works!!. however, while testing I've realised that 2 scenarios required to be updated.

1. Tag column is having 00 values but having correspond fael and mona values so in sum_days final column we should consider this which means tag is not always > then day(inv_dt). it can be both less and greater. I am unable to identify the condition to fix this. If you could please help.

2. We have one extra column tag1 which has no. of days values example 35, 23 and so on.. which we need to simply added in the final sum_days without any condition.

Comment: Hi - I don't understand point 1. if tag can be both less than and greater than there is no restriction and there seems to be no rule that can be applied to determine which record in ZT05 to select. Point 2 - just add the tag1 column to the "SUM_DAYS" calculation

Comment: Hi Nick, It will be 00 if we have only one vendor with one term and date. like I have updated in question. last row of the table ZT05

Comment: Hi Nick, Can adding condition (T2.ZTAGG > DAY(V_BKPF.BLDAT) or T2.ZTAGG = 00) works for this scenario ?
Also, I am getting -1 where tag, fael and, mona all are 00 or fael and mona are 00. How can I handle this to be 00 instead of -1 ?

Comment: Hi - you probably need to test any changes and then ask a question if you can't get them to work - having spent time debugging them - rather than (which appears to be what you're doing) asking if something will work before you've tried it. If you have '00' values causing issues then you'll probably need to use CASE statements to replace those '00' values (when they occur) with whatever value you want to use in those circumstances

Comment: Hi, 
I have tested the scenario with case statement and it is working now. However In the sum_days final column, How can we consider last day of the month when fael (day of the month) column has 31 as a value ?
for e.g.  I have inv_dt as 14-02-2023 and tag = 0, fael = 31, mona = 0 and tag1 = 45
while calculating the sum_days , it will select 31 as the last day of month and add 45(tag1) into it so it will be 17 days of feb + 45 days = 62 (wrong) as it should be 14 days of feb as there is 28 days in feb in 2023 year + 45 days(tag1) = 59(correct one)  

Could you please guide ?

Comment: Hi - I think you need to carefully think through all the possible scenarios and then create a question that provides sample data for all those scenarios and the result you want to achieve - and asks questions specifically where you are having issues. Then someone can help you with a single answer. For you to come up with a new scenario/question every time you previous question is answered is just wasting people's time

Comment: Hi,
Do we have any other option for the subquery `INNER JOIN ZT05 T1 ON ZLF.TERM = T1.TERM AND T1.TAG = 
    (SELECT MIN(T2.TAG) FROM ZT05 T2 WHERE ZLF.TERM = T2.TERM AND T2.TAG > DAY(ZBK.INV_DT) )`